# Carport Removal - Possible to DIY?

Tags: demolition, carport

https://imgur.com/gallery/0iamrtR

Hello all, just curious how possible it would be to DIY this carport removal. Out of the ~15 emails that I sent out for quotes, only 3 or so companies replied and said that they could even do this type of work, with quotes ranging from 4K - 7K.

I'm very ignorant on home improvement projects (coming from someone who just drilled into a water line in my wall last week). But I'm in between jobs/school for the next few weeks so I'm trying to get some projects done while I can. I haven't liked this carport since I purchased the home about 3 weeks ago and would like to remove it all together.

Basically just looking for tips on where to start and/or if possible to DIY some/all of this project. I'd definitely hire someone to come out and fix the fascia and roof, but I'd like to get as much done beforehand to cut some of the costs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not hard usually.  Start on top removing pieces.  The shingles will need dumping, but most of the wood can be kept or recycled if done carefully, not so much you redneck it with a chain and a pickup.

Comment: On an intentionally vague level, I'd start disassembling in the reverse order of the way you'd build something like this. Remove gutters, shingles, plywood cladding, and roof deck. Then you've got framing members you can cut off, being careful to protect your house's waterproofing and preventing insects/pests as you go. This is a big job and you'll either learn a lot or find you don't have the DIY skills to finish it.

Comment: Are you planning to remove the entire overhanging section? Or leave it at the shorter distance - i.e., overhanging the sidewalk? Either way you will need to deal with making a proper "edge" - gutter, etc. but more work if you are going back to the main part of the roof. Good news is that it doesn't look like there is any plumbing or electrical involved, so it is basically "remove and patch".

Comment: I actually just watched a video with someone that used a chain/pickup. Based on how it's attached, I think I ruled that option out. Honestly, I was thinking that I could just try out a chainsaw and cut across to the area that still covers the sidewalk to start things off. I'm undecided on whether I'd like to keep the area that hangs over the sidewalk. I wouldn't be opposed to keep it, as that section doesn't sag much, and would be nice to still have a "dry" area to store my girlfriend's plants, etc. Also - from the little that I know and can see, keeping that section would keep costs lower.

Comment: Is the chainsaw idea a bad one? If so - what tools would you guys recommend? I only have several, but am looking to add to the collection. And as far as waterproofing - is this type of project something that is best to do in 1 go or 1 day? If I can't complete in 1 day, would I just try tarping/taping the area that's exposed?

Comment: The best part about chaining your vehicle to a building/tree/whatever for planned demolition is the entertainment factor that everyone else gets when you post the "Hey, y'all, watch this!" video online. If you're actually planning on doing the demo work with a minimum of collateral damage, throw that option right out with the baby and the bath water.

Comment: Step one is to get a building permit. Your local AHJ should have a permit guide that includes the details they will inspect at your final inspection. That will give you a great start on what materials you need.

Comment: The hard part will be fixing the roof.  No way to tell how the carport roof is attached to the house roof.